# HTAccess Page Redirecting problem with & sign

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

I am trying to make my pages seo friendly.

I have a links in my page.

```
http://abc.com/test.php?Section=pages&title=feedback+%26+enquiry
```

it works fine and title has value "feedback & enquiry". I changed above link to:

```
http://abc.com/pages/feedback+%26+enquiry.htm
```

I wrote the htaccess code like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.htm$ index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.htm$ /test.php?Section=$1title=$2 [R]
```

i expected the same the result but i was surprised to see the error as the title is having value or "feedbac" and new variable "enquiry" being created with value ""

I am being unable to find the error. I guess its the htaccess conversion error. so how can i make it work?

I tried backescaping but got internal server error. My new htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.htm$ index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.htm$ index.php?Section=$1&title=$2 [R,B]
```

My Apache version is : 2.2.4

Comment: Drop punctuation characters in the query component, they look ugly and cause problems like you have. Unless you expect that there will be both titles `feedback & enquiry` and `feedback ! enquiry` (in which case you'd still need something suffixy to disambiguate `u & i` and `u + i`)

Comment: your suggestion of dropping & and ! is good but what if in anycase we need to do it? we cannot avoid it whole time

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Apache 2.2, you can use the `B` flag to escape any backreferences in your rewritten URL:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)\.htm$ /test.php?title=$1 [R,B]
```

Otherwise, in Apache 2.0, you can try using the internal `RewriteMap` `escape`:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)\.htm$ /test.php?title=${escape:$1} [R]
```

Comment: sorry it inform the lately change as i got error on my full url. I have edited my post and wrote my full url as i got internal server error while testing your given script with [B] options

Comment: @KoolKabin: If you're going to keep the `R` you should make sure your replacement is `/index.php?index.php?Section=$1&title=$2 [R,B]`, but really I don't think you want the `R` anymore? Also, what do your error logs say about the internal server error?

Comment: i am not getting any error code only internal server error message. May the the webmaster has configured to not to show error code/message. I tried with both options but both failed. Keeping escape will send title = ""

Answer (score 0):

[from the mod_rewrite doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

> Apache has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so backreferences (*$1*) will be unescaped at the time they are applied.

so your `feedback+%26+enquiry.htm` gets rewritten to `test.php?title=feedback+&+enquiry`, which, naturally, yields the result you see.

you can avoid the backreferences being unescaped by adding the `'B'` **(escape backreferences)** rewrite flag to your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)\.htm$ /test.php?title=$1 [R,B]
```

Comment: sorry it inform the lately change as i got error on my full url. I have edited my post and wrote my full url as i got internal server error while testing your given script with [B] options

Comment: make sure you do not have whitespace inside the `[R,B]`, ie. *not* `[R, B]`.

Comment: um.... i am preety sure that i dun have white space between them but still getting error